# Calling Async class from Async class in Android not working?

Tags: android, json, asynchronous, android-asynctask

So my goal is to load a random wikipedia page, get the title from it, and then use the wikipedia api to get the correct title to return for display (titles with special characters need "translated" to be able to display them correctly.) My problem comes when I use my JSONRequest class (Async) to try to execute the api url and create a JSON object. When it tries to execute, it freezes and doesn't go any further (but does not crash.) It isn't a problem with the URL, it is valid and works on desktop and mobile. This method was also used in another non-async class so I know it works there. My guess is that it is an async issue. This may be a stupid question with a simple answer, but any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    public class getRandom extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private static final String REQUEST_METHOD = "GET";
    private static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    String result, rawTitle;

    // Gets random wiki page and returns text to be loaded into search bar
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        String randomUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random";
        String titleApiUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=";

        // Get random title
        try {
            URL url = new URL(randomUrl);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //Set method and timeouts
            con.setRequestMethod(REQUEST_METHOD);
            con.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            con.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

            // Get status
            int status = con.getResponseCode();

            // Check for move or redirect and update url
            if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                    || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM) {
                String location = con.getHeaderField("Location");
                URL newUrl = new URL(location);
                con = (HttpURLConnection) newUrl.openConnection();
            }

            // Get name of page
            rawTitle = con.toString();
            int temp = rawTitle.indexOf("wiki/") + 5;
            rawTitle = rawTitle.substring(temp);

            con.disconnect();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            rawTitle = "Sailboats"; // Very random, totally not hard coded result.
        }

        // Ensure correct title format (use wiki api)
        try{
            // Get json from api
            JSONRequest wikiRequest = new JSONRequest();
            String wikiApiJsonString = wikiRequest.execute(titleApiUrl + rawTitle).get();

            // Create json object with returned string
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(wikiApiJsonString);

            // Get correct title from json
            result = jsonObj.getString("title");
        }
        catch(ExecutionException | InterruptedException |  JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = "Sailboats"; // Very random, totally not hard coded result.
        }

        return result;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, async tasks all run on the same thread.  So it won't actually start a second task until yours finishes.  Your options are:

1)Call executeOnExecutor instead of execute and tell it to use a new thread.

2)Architect your code such that you can make the request on this thread directly.  You're already on a thread, no reason to launch a new one.

3)Write your code such as you don't need to call .get().